# Avoid json key missing error using GSON lib

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit with GSON for consuming server data.

it's something like:

```
 MyRestClientClass.myGetDataMethod(params, new Callback<DataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void success(DataResponse dataResponse, Response response) {
            // success!

            //here I have acces to dataResponse object
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            // something went wrongd
        }
    });
```

And my POJO class:

```
    @Parcel
    public class DataResponse {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String myUserId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String userName;

    @SerializedName("adress")
    private String userAdress;

    //getter and setter
    }
```

So, when I receive JSON like:

```
    { "user_id":"id001",
      "name":"jhon",
      "adress":"ny"  }
```

it is working ok but I'd like to receive this object **without** `adress` key sometimes, and I got the error. Can I **check json keys if exists**, like in a custom json parser `if(json.has("adress"))` but keep using GSON lib? 
Have to notice, the project is big and it will take to long time to implement custom parser... Any advices will be apreciated!

Comment: Gson should set missing fields to null by default.

Comment: *"I got the error"* - what error? Gson doesn't have a built-in mechanism to differentiate between required vs. optional fields, so any field is optional by default. Hence, you shouldn't have to check for the existence of keys, as the runtime value of the annotated field will just end up being `null` if no key was found.